# Is there a way to determine which computer I need to hack in The Big Bank heist?

Tags: payday-2

I am trying to stealth the Big Bank heist but I keep getting spotted when cycling through all desktop machines that I need to hack to unlock the time lock door into the vault.  Is there a way I can tell which computer I need to hack without randomly guessing?

Bain does mention during the heist to try find clues to tell me which machine I need to hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes there is](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=272115971), but you need a teammate for it.

To explain, when you hack into the server, you will cause the computer that you need to hack to  display a message, like so:

[image: Computer]

Repeatedly hack into the server over and over while the rest of your team looks around at the computers until they find the one with the message on it.  The message disappears quickly if I remember correctly, so your teammates/you will have to keep your eyes peeled.  The guide also says the correct computer makes a beeping sound when you hack into the server (I don't remember any beeps, but I do know the message part is true).

Comment: God dammit Timmy Jim, just as I was proofreading my answer. +1 for faster reaction time.

Comment: You can kind of do it solo because you can listen to whoch direction the sound is coming from (if you have good headphones).